# calling an http url from a .net console application?

Tags: .net, url, console-application

Is it possible to call an http url from a .net console application?
can anyone give an idea.?

Comment: yes it is possible. What do you expect in response from HTTP request?

Comment: this http call will return only one string..its value will be either true or false

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public string DownloadUrl(string url)
{
    return new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(url);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a nice example if you are trying to [fetch HTML](http://www.csharp-station.com/HowTo/HttpWebFetch.aspx) from a web page using HTTP.

**UPDATE:**
As you have posted in comment that only thing you expect in response is a string would be good to use WebClient as [Chris Fulstow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8441655/293712) says in his answer.

```
System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible. Use the WebClient class.
See a tutorial here
http://www.dotnetperls.com/webclient